# What is the meaning of epoch in txid_current() in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT says

> The internal transaction ID type (xid) is 32 bits wide and wraps around every 4 billion transactions. However, these functions export a 64-bit format that is extended with an “epoch” counter so it will not wrap around during the life of an installation

What is the meaning of this *epoch* in this sentence? Is this a counter of how many times the xid reached 4billion transactions and was reseted to zero?

Do I understand correctly that `txid_current()` returns a 64-bit number  which is basically composed from two 32 bit numbers concatenated together? This first 32 bits are an epoch counter (which starts at 0) and the last 32 bits are xid?

I assume that when `xid` reaches its maximum value the epoch counter will be bumped to 0 and the `xid` resets to 0. Which, I assume, basically makes the `txid_current()` behave like a normal 64-bit numer.

Is that how it works? I have a hard time understanding this.

Answer (score 2):

Epoch is used to prevent txid_current() from wrapping around and starting from zero (or to be exact from 3 because values 0,1,2 re used internally).

So it works lite this:

Postgres has an internal 32bit xid counter which is different than the value returned by txid_current(). The internal xid wraps around and resets its counting at every wraparound.

The txid_current(), on the other hand, returns 64bit (bigint) in which the high bits are an epoch increment which happens once per xid wrap around and does not start from zero.

So at every wraparound the epoch kicks in and the high bits of  txid_current() get modified to prevent txids from resetting, and instead txids keep incrementing until the 64bit limit is reached (sometimes in a very far future long after we all die).